# deleted operator hides class operator?

Tags: c++

I have found a very strange issue when revisiting and updating any old library. I have the following code

```
class bmint_tmp;
class bmfloat_tmp;

template<typename T> struct bop_return{typedef bmint_tmp type;};
template<> struct bop_return<float>{typedef bmfloat_temp type;};

class bmint
{
    template<typename T> friend typename bop_return<T>::type operator+(const T& l, const bmint& r);
/** irrelevant code **/
};
template<typename T> typename bop_return<T>::type operator+(const T& l, const bmint& r)
{
    return r.operator+(l);
}
template<> typename bop_return<bmint_tmp>::type operator+(const bmint_tmp& l, const bmint_tmp& r)=delete;
```

I have deleted this template instantiation because I prefer to get called the existing bmint_tmp::operator+, implemented as member method in another file. But, when compiling it seems that gcc dont see nothing but this deleted operator, and says:
**error: use of deleted function 'typename::bigmath::bop_return::type bigmath::operator+(const T&, const bigmath::bmint&) [with T=...**
I have attempted to change modifiers (remove const specification, for example), but my many attempts are unsuccessful. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, if a function is deleted then it still *exists* (and it's even considered to be defined!), with everything that implies… you just can't actually call it.

Use `enable_if`, instead, so that the template specialisation cannot be instantiated at all. Then the only candidate will be the operator function you want.

Comment: @Mel: That was quick! Good job.